# test "handled exceptions" junit

Tags: exception, junit

I have a method with a handled exception:

```
public boolean exampleMethod(){

    try{
      Integer temp=null;
      temp.equals(null);
      return
      }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

I want to test it

```
public void test_exampleMethod(){}
```

I have tried

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException expectedException=ExpectedException.none();

public void test_exampleMethod(){
    expectedException.expect(JsonParseException.class);
    exampleMethod();
}
```

but that doesnt work because the exception is handled inside.

I also tried

```
@Test(expected=JsonParseException.class)
```

but same issue...the exception is handled

I know that I can just do

```
assertTrue(if(exampleMethod()))
```

but it will still print the stack trace to the log. I would prefer clean logs...Any suggestions?

Comment: Your example does not comple, you need a return statement atthe end of your method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot test what a method is doing internally. This is completely hidden (unless there are side effects, that are visible outside).

The test can check that for a specific *input* the method returns a expected *output*. But you can not check, how this is done. So you have no way to detect if there was a exception that you have handled.

So: either don't handle the exception (let the test catch the exception), or return a special value that tells you about the exception.

Anyway, I hope your real exception handling is more sensible than in your example.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there is a way to see them. Alas, I will live with dirty logs.

Yeah those were as "simple" of exception handling examples as I could think of and not real code.

Answer (score 1):

If the method does not throw an exception you cannot expect to get one!

Below an example how write a Junit Test for a method that throws an Exception:

```
class Parser {
    public void parseValue(String number) {
        return Integer.parseInt(number);
    }
}
```

Normal test case

```
public void testParseValueOK() {
    Parser parser = new Parser();
    assertTrue(23, parser.parseValue("23"));     
}
```

Test case for exception

```
public void testParseValueException() {
    Parser parser = new Parser();
    try {
       int value = parser.parseValue("notANumber");   
       fail("Expected a NumberFormatException");
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
       // as expected got exception
    }
}
```