# How to test already handled exception using jUnit?

Tags: java, exception, junit

I am new to jUnit. Can not figure out how to test handled exception.

```
 public File inputProcessor(String filePath){
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = new File(filePath);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.print("Check your input file path");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file;
}
```

Now, want to test with a invalid file path to check whether exception is thrown and caught properly. I wrote this

```
@Test (expected = java.io.FileNotFoundException.class)
public void Input_CheckOnInvalidPath_ExceptionThrown() {
    Driver driver = new Driver();
    String filePath = "wrong path";
    File file = driver.inputProcessor(filePath);
      }
```

But as I have already caught my exception its not working. Test is failing . Any help will   be great!! thnx

Comment: If the exception isn't thrown even though you provoked it, then it was caught correctly. What's the problem?

Comment: Why are you testing for a behavior which the method doesn't exhibit in the first place!?

Comment: Have you checked the solution proposed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955899/test-handled-exceptions-junit) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184281/how-to-handle-exceptions-while-unit-testing-using-junit)

Comment: As stated in @TreyJonn's link: Tests are supposed to test exposed behavior, not implementation details. If you need to test only parts of a method (i.e. *how* the exception is handled specifically), it is a sign that your method already does too much and needs to be split into several methods that can then be tested (but which maybe should not be `public`).

Comment: @rocketboy didnt get your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test your method's behavior, not its in implementation details.

If the correct behavior of your method is to return `null` when the file does not exist, you just need

```
@Test
public void Input_CheckOnInvalidPath_ExceptionThrown() {
    Driver driver = new Driver();
    String filePath = "wrong path";
    assertNull(driver.inputProcessor(filePath));
  }
```

If the correct behavior of your method is to print a particular message to `System.out` when the file does not exist, and you want to test that, then you can create a mock `PrintStream`, use `System.setOut(PrintStream)` to set it, call your method, and then test that the `PrintStream` was invoked correctly.  Mockito can help you do that -- maybe.  I think you run the risk of testing the implementation detail that `System.out.println()` vs many `System.out.print()` is invoked.  (You probably shouldn't be testing how `e.printStackTrace()` is implemented.)

If the correct behavior is both, then you need both checks.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy for a clear and concise answer.                      "You need to test your method's behaviour, not its in implementation   details " - I never think of this concept.

Comment: I literally said the same in my comment above: "Tests are supposed to test exposed behavior, not implementation details."

Comment: Yes sure you did! Thank you. As I said just started to grasp the whole idea of unit testing, Its easy to understand with snippets!

Answer (score 1):

The exposed behavior you need from the method is the appearance of appropriate lines in `System.out` and `System.err`. In your test code, you can replace System.out and System.err with your own `PrintStream`. See [System.setOut](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) and [System.setErr](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29).

Base each PrintStream on e.g. a StringWriter. That way, in your test code you can pick up the String representing what, if anything, the method wrote to each output stream, and do tests on it.